# Initialize std::array with make_shared

Tags: arrays, c++11, exception-safety, make-shared

## Background

I am writing a driver for a networkprotocol and have a function `write(std::shared_ptr<package> package)`, where `package` is `std::array<buffer_ptr,2>` (0=>header, 1=> body). For convenience I want to write a function `write(buffer_ptr body)`, that autogenerates the header and calls the first form of `write`. To do so I want to us `std::make_shared`, however I have issues initializing the `std::array` from the `make_shared` call.

## Code

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> buffer_ptr;
typedef std::array<buffer_ptr, 2> package_t;
typedef std::shared_ptr<package_t> package_ptr;

void connection::write(package_ptr package) {
    ... //do stuff
}

void connection::write(buffer_ptr body) {
    buffer_ptr header = buildHeader(body);
    write(std::make_shared<package_t>(???)) //here I want to initialize the array with {header,body}
}
```

## What I tried for ???

(these led to compiler errors)

```
{header, body}
{{header, body}}
std::initializer_list<buffer_ptr>{header, body}
```

## Question:

1. Is there a solution to make this work or do I have to write something like:

   package_ptr package=new package{header, body};
   write(package);

   1.b) Do I loose efficency by having to resort to `package_ptr(new package)`? (I remember make shared allocating memory for the pointer and the instance in one chunk, to save memory requests)
2. On [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) is reads:

   > Moreover, f(shared_ptr(new int(42)), g()) can lead to memory leak
   >   if g throws an exception. This problem doesn't exist if make_shared is
   >   used.

   Why would memory be leaked (could `int(42)` be constructed before `g` is called, and `g` be called before `shared_ptr` is called)? And would the alternative code from 1. suffer from such a potential leak?

Comment: `write(std::make_shared<package_t>( package_t{header, body} ));`

Comment: @Cubbi Nice! microsoft compiler didn't like it though :(

Comment: @Cubbi: what happens if `make_shared` throws(i.e. out of memory)? WIll the already constructed `package_t` be leaked?

Comment: @ted no, it will call the destructors of its two members.

Comment: @Cubbi what will call the destructor of its two members? `package_t`? Would you mind pointing me to the difference to the example in 2.) in the question where this apparently does not work according to cpp reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

`array` doesn't explicitly declare a constructor. In particular, it doesn't have a constructor that takes a initializer list.

I think a clean way is to avoid the explicit `new` in the code and leave it to standard functions:

```
package_t p = {header, body};
write(std::make_shared<package_t>(p));
```

The code would have looked even better if there was neither `new` nor `std::shared_ptr` :

```
package_t p = {header, body};
write(p);
```

Second, on [Cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) it reads:

> Moreover, f(shared_ptr(new int(42)), g())
>   can lead to memory leak if g throws an exception. This problem doesn't
>   exist if make_shared is used.

The standard doesn't specify an order for evaluating function arguments and expressions can be evaluated in any order as long as they produce the same result.

In

```
f(shared_ptr(new int(42)), g())
```

`new int(42)` has to precede `shared_ptr()` but not `g()` and this can cause a leak if `g` throws.

In

```
f(make_shared<int>(42), g())
```

the allocation happens inside `make_shared`. If `g` is called before `make_shared` and if it throws, the memory would never get allocated.

If `make_shared` is called before `g` and if `g` throws, the `shared_ptr` object would have been created already and it's destruction is guaranteed because of RAII

Comment: the `shared_pointer` has to stay, because it goes through an async write and the pointer is used to release the header/body after the write calls the callback